# Why is the variable 'loan' not being recognized?

Tags: java

In public Amortization I declared the variable loan, but in calcPayment the variable isn't being recognized. I would just use loanBalance but we need both loanBalance and loanAmount

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Amortization {
    private double loanAmount; // holds the amount of the loan
    private double interestRate; // holds the interest rate
    private double loanBalance; // holds the monthly balance
    private double term; // utilized in order to calculate the monthly payments
    private double payment; // holds the cash amount of the monthly payments
    private int loanYears; // holds the number of years in the loan
    
    public Amortization(double loan, double rate, int years) {
        loanAmount = loan;
        loanBalance = loan;
        loanYears = years;
        calcPayment();
        
    }
    
    private void calcPayment() {
        term = Math.pow((1+interestRate/12),(loanYears*12));
        payment = (loan * (interestRate/12) * term)/(term - 1);
        
    }
    
    
    
    
}
```

I went back into public Amortization and typed out the variable 'loan' and it was recognized

Comment: In `public Amortization(double loan, double rate, int years) { ...`, `loan`, `rate`, and `years` are local variables. Their scope is limited to that method.  Perhaps you meant `payment = (loanAmount * (interestRate/12) * term)/(term - 1);` in `calcPayment ()` ?

Answer (score -2):

You have the variable not created. You have it as parameter of the constructor where you are using it to initialize other variables.

Solution: if you want it as a new variable, just create it.

```
private int loan;
```